# CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C:/Program Files/vtk/bin/CMakeCache.txt.tmpc3fcf for VTK

Tags: cmake, vtk

I am trying to build [VTK](https://vtk.org/download/) version 9.2.2 with CMake for a few days now, but no luck so far. I am getting the below error in CMake GUI:

```
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C:/Program Files/vtk/bin/CMakeCache.txt.tmpc3fcf
CMake Error: Unable to (re)create the private pkgRedirects directory:
C:/Program Files/vtk/bin/CMakeFiles/pkgRedirects
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. C:/Program Files/vtk/bin/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
```

I am following the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgvbhyDh8r0&t=23s), but it still does not work for me. I have tried to search for answers for a while, but there doesn't seem to be the exact same error that I am having on the internet anywhere.

I am on Windows 10, using VTK 9.2.2 and my CMake version is 3.25.1. I also tried with multiple versions of visual studio in the configuration, but it returned the same error.

---

The steps I have taken were:

1. Download VTK from the site
2. Put the downloaded files into the program files directory
3. Made a `/src` and `/bin` folder under a `/vtk` folder, which is outside the downloaded package
4. Copied and pasted the downloaded files into the `/src` folder
5. Opened CMake GUI and chose the src folder as the source and chose the bin folder as the build folder
6. Clicked generate and it threw the errors above

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added more details/steps to my post. Please have a look. I will also try to put the downloaded files into some other directory that doesn't require root user permission.

Comment: "2. Put the downloaded files into the program files directory" - Never do that. The directory `C:/Program Files/` is for ready-to-use, installed programs and persistent files related to that programs. Source files for VTK are not the ready-to-use programs, so they shouldn't be under `C:/Program Files/`. A build directory is a place where CMake will create intermediate files for build, and where projects's artifacts will be built. So, a build directory should be outside of `C:/Program Files/` too.

Comment: "2. Put the downloaded files into the program files directory" and "4. Copied and pasted the downloaded files into the `/src` folder" - Why do you **duplicate** the source files? If you choose build directory to be outside of the source directory, then CMake will never write into the source directory, so there is no reason to copy its content.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, I have gotten the build to work with CMake GUI. Please post your comments as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message like

```
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: ...
```

usually occurred when CMake has no **permissions** to write a given file.

Your case involves directories under `C:/Program Files/`, which are usually configured as read-only for normal users.

The file `CMakeCache.txt` is created in the **build directory**, so the error message about such file usually means problem with a build directory.

A build directory should always be writable by the regular user. Here CMake creates files for the build tool, and here a build tool creates intermediate and resulted files.

Comment: I'm running the CMake GUI from their (presumably "portable") .zip unpacked somewhere, launching `cmake-gui` via its full path, while the current working dir is the prj (build) root. Here  `/CMakeCache.txt.tmp97e63` is the non-writable file, which is clearly a bogus path. What may be missing? (Running just `cmake` the same way works fine, I could build the debug version of this 3-rd-party prj, but I'm trying to switch to release mode, to no avail...) Any pointes, where to look?

Comment: @Sz.: Without the exact error message it is difficult to guess the reason of the problem. You are better to prepare a **new question**, where you describe your actions, provide the exact error message and other information.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I just assumed that perhaps it's a common beginner pattern. The actual problem isn't worth the trouble of a proper question. (In fact, for me CMake as a whole isn't. There hasn't been a single case yet where the ridiculous extra complexity, ~hundred MBs bloat, hopeless debugging of random obscure errors etc. couldn't have been avoided by a trivial batch script or two for building from scratch. And I carry a pair of gnumake/nmake in my back pocket for the really complicated cases.)